# Maven - adding the same dependency with different classifier causes OutOfMemoryError

Tags: maven, out-of-memory, maven-3

I've got Java application, which is built by Maven 3.0.3 (MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m).

In pom.xml file I've got dependency to another component:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.component</groupId>
    <artifactId>component-core</artifactId>
    <version>component.110</version>
<dependency>
```

I want to use some classes from this component, which are packed as test:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.component</groupId>
    <artifactId>component-core</artifactId>
    <version>component.110</version>
    <classifier>tests</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

After adding this dependency I can not compile my application, because of:

```
[ERROR] Java heap space -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/OutOfMemoryError
```

When I use only main dependency or only tests classifier dependency everything is compiling and working. how can I use both of them?

I will be grateful for any help.

Best regards,
Chris

Edit:

Full stack trace is:

```
[ERROR] Java heap space -> [Help 1]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.IdentityHashMap.resize(IdentityHashMap.java:452)
    at java.util.IdentityHashMap.put(IdentityHashMap.java:428)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.graph.transformer.JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.buildConflictGroups(JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.java:116)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.graph.transformer.JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.buildConflictGroups(JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.java:129)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.graph.transformer.JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.buildConflictGroups(JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.java:129)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.graph.transformer.JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.buildConflictGroups(JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.java:129)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.graph.transformer.JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.buildConflictGroups(JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.java:129)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.graph.transformer.JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.buildConflictGroups(JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.java:129)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.graph.transformer.JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.buildConflictGroups(JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.java:129)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.graph.transformer.JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.buildConflictGroups(JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.java:129)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.graph.transformer.JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.buildConflictGroups(JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.java:129)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.graph.transformer.JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.buildConflictGroups(JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.java:129)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.graph.transformer.JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.buildConflictGroups(JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.java:129)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.graph.transformer.JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.buildConflictGroups(JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.java:129)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.graph.transformer.JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.transformGraph(JavaEffectiveScopeCalculator.java:64)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.graph.transformer.ChainedDependencyGraphTransformer.transformGraph(ChainedDependencyGraphTransformer.java:75)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:253)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
```

Comment: Can you run it with -X? Just to see where it fail...

Comment: Could you try with a newer version of Maven? This seems like a bug. Try with at least `3.0.5`. There's already a `3.2.1`. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @carlspring I'm using Java 1.6u51 x64. I'm going to test on Maven 3.2.1

Comment: @carlspring My project is not compiling under Maven 3.2.1, but **I tried under 3.0.5 and it works!** You were right that it is Maven bug. Thanks for help! Now I have to force version change, what can be not easy :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to at least Maven `3.0.5`. This looks like a bug in Maven. Consider upgrading to an even later version as well, such as `3.2.1`.